Is it possible that before creating a copy of shared_ptr the original shared_ptr goes out of scope
With below code snippet is it ever possible that output will print "Shared Ptr out of scope"?
What I am trying is before a shared copy is made the orginal shard_ptr goes out of scope. I am aware that shared_ptr has a atomic ref_count. but what if copy constructor of Test is invoked before creating a copy of shared_ptr and meanwhile in main thread shared_ptr sp goes out of scope.
I've tried by changing the order of arguments to function foo and it has same result, i.e if block is executed, Shared Ptr has value 9 is printed.
struct Test
{
    Test() = default;
    Test(const Test& t)
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            std::cerr << "I am sleeping----\n";
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);
        }
    }
};

void foo(std::shared_ptr<int> sp, Test t)
{
    if (sp)
        std::cerr << "Shared Ptr has value "<<*sp;
    else
        std::cerr << "Shared Ptr out of scope";
}
int main()
{
    std::thread t;
    {
        Test tst;
        auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(9);
        t = std::move(std::thread(foo,sp, tst));
    }
    if(t.joinable())
    t.join();
}


No, there is no chance that sp in test will be null.
std::thread(foo,sp, tst)

Is a synchronization point and sp will be copied into the thread before the code can move forward.  That means that even when the scope exits the thread still has a valid copy keeping the pointer alive.

The sp in foo will never be invalid, so foo will never print the "out of scope" message.
The std::thread constructor runs in the context of the main thread, not in the context of the thread being created.  So the copies of both sp and tst happen there, before even moving the object to t.
The reference count for the shared object may get as high as 3, if the thread actually starts before the block concludes and sp is destroyed (3 references -- sp in main, a copy in the std::thread object, and sp in foo.)  Or it may never be higher than 2, if sp is destroyed before the thread starts running and calls foo, or if the invoke of foo in the new thread involves a move instead of a copy.
